# Why am I getting an is not defined error?

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a program that allows two people to play tic tac toe. They should select a row and then a column, then the token should be placed in that location. I'm new to multidimensional lists and i'm struggling a bit. This is what I have so far:

```
def showBoard():
    board = [[0,0,0,],
             [0,0,0],
             [0,0,0]]    

    print("-------------")
    print('|',board[0][0], '|',board[0][1], '|',board[0][2],'|')
    print("|---+---+---|")
    print ('|',board[1][0], '|',board[1][1], '|',board[1][2],'|')
    print("|---+---+---|")
    print ('|',board[2][0], '|',board[2][1], '|',board[2][2],'|')
    print("-------------")


def playerX():

    row = input("Enter a row (0, 1, or 2) for player X: ")
    column = input("Enter a column (0 , 1, or 2) for player X: ")
    board[row][column] = "X"


def main():

    showBoard()
    playerX()



main()
```

But then it always throws the error builtins.NameError: name 'board' is not defined.
Can I do it using similar code to what I have? Or will I need to use the append() somehow?

Comment: Please format your code properly. This is almost definitely a scoping issue, but that's hard to diagnose when you obfuscated the scoping in your code.

Comment: From the looks of it though, it looks like you have `board` defined inside of `showBoard`, meanings its only accessible from inside `showBoard`.

Comment: @carcigenicate I tried putting everything into main and now i'm getting builtins.TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str error. This seems to be very frustrating.

Comment: The solution to scoping problems isn't to stick everything into the same function, it's to learn what scoping is, and use it to your advantage. And the new error is because you're trying to index the list with a string. `board["1"]` isn't allowed. You need to turn the string into a number using `int` before trying to index with it. `input` returns strings, not numbers.

Comment: @carcigenicate Ahh I see now. Thank you so much, that was a big help. I was able to create a working function that doesn't give any errors now. Thanks again, and sorry for the poor formatting... I'm still getting used to formatting on this site.

Comment: Np. If my answer below helped you, you can hit the checkmark to mark your question as solved. Also, just a tip for formatting, when you paste code into the editor, highlight it and press ctrl+k. That will auto-format it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you're defining `board` inside `drawBoard`, then trying to use it in `playerX`. Variables defined inside a scope (like a function) can't be used outside of that scope. If you need to use the variable elsewhere, define it globally, or better yet, pass it in as an argument:

```
def newBoard():
    # Create a new board, then return it
    #  so it can be used elsewhere. 
    return [[0,0,0],
            [0,0,0],
            [0,0,0]]   

def showBoard(board):
    print("-------------")
    print('|',board[0][0], '|',board[0][1], '|',board[0][2],'|')
    print("|---+---+---|")
    print ('|',board[1][0], '|',board[1][1], '|',board[1][2],'|')
    print("|---+---+---|")
    print ('|',board[2][0], '|',board[2][1], '|',board[2][2],'|')
    print("-------------")

def playerX(board):
    row = int(input("Enter a row (0, 1, or 2) for player X: ")) 
    column = int(input("Enter a column (0 , 1, or 2) for player X: ")) 

    board[row][column] = "X"

def main():
    board = newBoard() 

    showBoard(board)
    playerX(board)

main()
```

What I changed:

- I created a `newBoard` function that creates a new board. I then used it in `main` to create a board.
- I made `drawBoard` and `playerX` accept the board as arguments. I then passed the board I created in `main` into each.
- I made it so inputs are converted to numbers before they're used for indexing.